# "configure: error: Package requirements (blkid) were not met"

Tags: compiling, libraries, pkg-config

I'm trying to build btrfs-progs from sources, but when I run ./configure I get the error:

```
checking for BLKID... no
configure: error: Package requirements (blkid) were not met:

No package 'blkid' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BLKID_CFLAGS
and BLKID_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

`blkid` is installed in `/sbin` so, presumably, all its libraries are in the default locations.

What do I need to do tell pkg-config where `blkid` is or am I actually missing a package?

FYI: I'm running Debian 8 (sid/unstable) with a 4.1.0 kernel built from github.com/torvalds/linux.git sources about a week ago (commit:g6aaf0da).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are missing packages, you can use `apt-cache`:

```
% apt-cache search blkid
libblkid-dev - block device id library - headers and static libraries
libblkid1 - block device id library
```

or even:

```
% apt-cache search blkid | grep '\-dev'
libblkid-dev - block device id library - headers and static libraries
```

We know that we need the development libraries to compile something, therefore do a...

```
apt-get install libblkid-dev
```

...as `root` user.

Answer (score 2):

When you're building a binary from source that links to a particular library, the build process requires a few extra ("header") files related to that library that aren't needed during runtime, so they are not installed along with the base library package (since other distro packages which need the library itself are  already built binaries).

On Debian, the extra files are in `-dev` packages.  The actual library here is `libblkid`, so you need:

```
apt-get install libblkid-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
apt-get build-dep btrfs-tools
```

to get all the build-dependencies including `libblkid-dev`.

Comment: That will install the build dependencies for the `btrfs-tools` version in your package repository, rather than for the newer version you're trying to build. It will still work most of the time, but might not suffice when the newer version of `btrfs-tools` has added new dependencies (like back in the day when mainline btrfs already supported some newer compression algorithm, but Debian's version didn't know about it yet).

Comment: Yes, thats true, but normally `.configure` will test for this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for arch-distros:

```
sudo pacman -S util-linux libutil-linux
```